# A value of type 'Color' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

i got an error while using Colors.black property from the material.dart library.

**Error** : A value of type 'Color' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'String'.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Category {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String color;

  const Category({
    @required this.id, 
    @required this.title, 
    this.color = Colors.black,
    });
}
```

[image]

any help will be appreciated

Comment: The answer in this case is quite simple. If you see a message that the bicycle wheel cannot be used as a car steering wheel, you may be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to assign a type Color to a Variable of type String, change:

```
final String color;
```

for:

```
final Color color;
```

Dart is a strongly-typed language, it prohibits you from assigning a value of another type to a variable that had it's type declared.
Both `Color` and `String` are `Objects` in Dart, but have different types.

When you're not sure about the type you'll be passing to a variable, declare it with the keyword `var`:

```
var color;
```

This way you can assign any type to it. Thou it's not advised, since this way you won't be enjoying the benefits you gain from using a strongly-typed language such as Dart.

Answer (score 2):

```
final String color;
```

Declares a variable called `color` of type `String`.

```
this.color = Colors.black
```

Is assigning an object of type `Color` to the `String` variable.

Change `final String color` to `final Color color`.

Answer (score 1):

you can make color's type

```
final Color color ; or final int color;
```